# Run multiple war's with gradle and tomcat in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans, gradle

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE, gradle and tomcat 6.
I've creates a root-project with some sub-projects:

- rootproject

  - frontend (war)
  - rest (war)
  - data (jar)

What I want know is, deploy the rootproject (or frontend) and then deploy the frontend-war and rest-war to the embedded and local tomcat server.
I tried the Cargo plugin with identifier [com.bmuschko.cargo](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) but there's no way to configure it right, so it can run like i want.

Some stuff on the internet says, that this isn't working well or isn't possible...

Has anyone an idea, how to solve this?
Should i use maven instead?

Here are my configuration files:

**Rootproject build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.0.3'
    }
}


import org.gradle.api.artifacts.*



apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'

subprojects { 
    apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper, description: 'Creates and deploys the Gradle wrapper to the current directory.') {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}

dependencies {
    def cargoVersion = '1.4.5'
    cargo "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:$cargoVersion",
          "org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:$cargoVersion"
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat6x'

    deployable {
        file = project(':Frontend').war.archivePath
        context = 'frontend'
    }

    deployable {
        file = project(':Rest').war.archivePath
        context = 'rest'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = file('C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache Tomcat 6.0.35')
    }
}

[cargoDeployRemote, cargoRunLocal]*.dependsOn project(':Frontend').war, project(':Rest').war
```

**Rootproject common.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

String mavenGroupId = 'rootproject'
String mavenVersion = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // Adding dependencies here will add the dependencies to each subproject.
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

String mavenArtifactId = name

group = mavenGroupId
version = mavenVersion

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes, description: 'Creates a jar from the source files.') {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
    archives sourcesJar
}

configure(install.repositories.mavenInstaller) {
    pom.project {
        groupId = mavenGroupId
        artifactId = mavenArtifactId
        version = mavenVersion
    }    
}

task createFolders(description: 'Creates the source folders if they do not exist.') doLast {
    sourceSets*.allSource*.srcDirs*.each { File srcDir ->
        if (!srcDir.isDirectory()) {
            println "Creating source folder: ${srcDir}"
            srcDir.mkdirs()
        }
    }
}
```

**Frontend build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '/src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir '/src/main/java'
            include '**/*.xml'
        }
    }
}

war {
    archiveName = 'Frontend.war'
    exclude('**/*.java,**/*.form')
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
                    'javax.servlet:jsp-api:2.0'

    compile project(':Data')

    compile 'antlr:antlr:2.7.6'
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible with the Gradle Cargo plugin?

Comment: Can you tell me, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are mixing up multiple concerns in your question. Let me see if I can give you an answer based on what I understand.

You are trying to deploy two WARs created by two different subprojects that are part of a Gradle multi-project build. The Gradle Cargo plugin only supports local or remote containers so I am not sure why you are mentioning an embedded container. For now let's assume we want to deploy to a locally installed Tomcat 6 container.

In the following Cargo plugin configuration, I assume the subprojects to have the project paths `:frontend` and `:rest` (they might be different for you). I'd put this configuration into the build script of root project.

```
cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat6x'

    deployable {
        file = project(':frontend').war.archivePath
        context = 'frontend'
    }

    deployable {
        file = project(':rest').war.archivePath
        context = 'rest'
    }

    local {
        homeDir = file('...')
    }
}

[cargoDeployRemote, cargoRunLocal]*.dependsOn project(':frontend').war, project(':rest').war
```

I don't think NetBeans is really relevant for answering your question. In the IDE you can simply call the corresponding Gradle task. Deployment order shouldn't matter as long as you create the correct project dependencies. You might also want to watch this video on ["Web Application Deployments With Gradle"](http://youtu.be/mWwN3PrcJUc) to better understand what can be done in Gradle today.

Comment: Okay, that looks perfect. I've inserted the configuration into my build script of the root-project. Now I've got the following error: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'war' on project ':Frontend'.

Comment: I've added my configuration files in my question above

Comment: Sounds like you generally should get a deeper understanding of Gradle. `war` is the task name that generates your WAR file. If it has a different name in your project, then you'll have to change the code. Also make sure you use the correct project path. This can be examined via `gradle projects`.